# Spyder IDE - Run file with mpiexec

Tags: python, anaconda, mpi, spyder

I'm using mip4py and I am able to run my code from the command prompt using `mpiexec -n 4 python myfile.py`. I want to use the 'run' button in Spyder to do the same, how do I go about integrating my custom run command (or mpi) with Spyder run?

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) Does that command require user interaction?

Comment: No, essentially just need to prepend `mpiexec -n 4` to the python run command, no interaction.

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) You can run your file with our Run button by putting the following code in a *different* file:

```
from IPython import get_ipython
ip = get_ipython()
ip.run_cell("!mpiexec -n 4 python myfile.py")
```

*Note:* It's very important that you use a different file to not cause an infinite recursion while evaluating the above code.